# Button creating another column in Panel

Tags: java, swing

The button on the Panel was supposed to be below the last row of ovals but what it does was add a column:

[image]

Here is my Code

```
    Panel p1 = new Panel();
    JButton shiftLeft = new JButton("Shift Left");
    JButton shiftRight = new JButton("Shift Right");

    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(Rows, Columns));
    for (int i=0; i<Rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++) {
            arcs[i][j] = new ArcsPanel(i, j);
            p1.add(arcs[i][j]);
            arcs[i][j].addMouseListener(me);
        }
    }
    p1.add(shiftRight);
    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand **what is your question**.

Comment: That is the way components are added to a grid layout. If you want to stick to a grid layout, you can add some sort of empty panel for a filler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The button on the Panel was supposed to be below the last row of ovals

A GridLayout always adds components in rows/columns.

If you want the button separate from the GridLayout then you need to add the button to the frame directly:

```
//p1.add(shiftRight);
add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(shiftRight, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Or if you don't want the button resized, then you need to wrap it in another panel first:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add( shiftRight );
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

The point is to achieve desired layout you can use multiple panels each with different layouts. You are not force to use a single panel or layout manager.